# Structure of the yaml file and correct parameters when calling 'populate_page_with data_for(?)' , if the web elements are defined as arrays?

Tags: ruby, yaml, page-object-gem

I'm writing automated tests in Ruby, using page-object and data-magic.

There's a table containing on each row a field that I want to write in, using `populate_page_with data_for(key, additional={})` and taking the input values from a yaml file. I've defined an array of those text_fields, but I don't know how the yaml file should look for it, nor how I should call the `data_for` method afterwards.

Here's what I've tried:

Yaml file content:

`edit_table:
    row_number: 0
    description_elements[%{row_number}]: ~sentences(sentence_count = 1)`

Page Object file content:

`class TestClass
text_fields :description, id: /_description$/
def write_description(row_number)
    populate_page_with data_for(:edit_table, { 'row_number' => row_number })
end`

There's no error thrown for this code, but the method doesn't write anything in the field.

I'm new to Yaml, so I have no idea if this is even close to what it should look like; it's just something that I thought to try. Please explain to me how I should write the yaml file and how to call the method, in order to be able to write in one of the fields from the defined array.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**

The `populate_page_with` method takes a hash where the keys match a method of the page object. In your code, you are basically asking the page object to do:

```
page.row_number = 1
page.description_elements[%{row_number}] = "Voluptatem expedita odio aut fugit quibusdam."
```

However, since the page object has neither of those two methods, they just get ignored (which is why there are no errors).

In the end, the `populate_page_with` probably is not a good choice for what you are trying to do.

**Solution**

Given your attempted code, it looks like you just want to set a text field, found by row number, to a sentence. In that case, you could simply get the text field and then set it based on data from the YAML file.

The YAML can be simply be like below. Since you get the `data_for` each time, the description will change per field.

```
edit_table:
  description: ~sentences(sentence_count = 1)
```

The page object would then be as follows. Notice that the `text_fields` accessor has created a method `description_elements`, which returns an array of matching elements. Therefore, you can access the row_number using the `[]` method.

```
class TestClass
  text_fields :description, id: /_description$/

  def write_description(row_number)
    description_elements[row_number] = data_for(:edit_table)['description']
  end
end
```

Which you could then use to input the nth row. For example, to input the second row (noting the 0-based index):

```
page.write_description(1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now I understand better how populate_page_with data_for actually works. The thing is I have several fields in each table row (I simplified the problem in my initial question) and I liked the idea of writing in all of them at once from the same line of code. But I understand why you say it wouldn't work.

Comment: You can probably achieve what you want - likely by using a widget that has a `populate_page_with` method and the necessary setters. However, without a specific scenario and API you want to achieve, it is hard to give a specific answer.